# Start Up Error - Happen through the Night

Tags: boot

I get the image attached happening every other time I reboot my Pi whether it is gracefull or not. I left it running overnight and it was still happening this morning.

It just keeps printing `mmc0: fsm 1, hsts 1` on the screen over and over.

Any ideas?[image: A photograph of a black screen with vertically repeated white text that reads mmc0: fsm 1, hsts 1 with time stamps to the left.]

Answer (score 2):

mmc is presumably the multi-media card, that is the SD card.

The Pi does not seem to like your SD card.

Perhaps try reformatting or rewriting the card.

Comment: This answer is supported by [this raspberrypi.org forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=184700).